# Codes in onAnimationRepeat is not running

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to do some things  in `onAnimationRepeat` .
its my code:

```
final LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);

//line 03

        RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 0);
        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setRepeatCount(4);
        anim.setDuration(10);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
//line 01
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(
                        R.layout.product_layout, null);
                TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test);
                t.setText(i + "");

                View root = v.findViewById(R.id.root);
                View face = v.findViewById(R.id.face);
                View back = v.findViewById(R.id.back);

                l.addView(v);
                flipCard(root, face, back);
//line 02
                i++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        l.startAnimation(anim);
```

but it not working.
when I copy `line 01` - `line 02` codes into `line 03` both of them (copied codes and `line 01` - `line 02` codes) be performed.

what is problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved.

`LinearLayout l` was defined with

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

and it was empty.
I changed it to

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

and my problem is solved.